# Add finished speaking callback to text-to-speech function

Tags: c#, wpf, text-to-speech

I'm using this code that works perfectly except I want to add the ability to know when a `startSpeaking` call is done speaking.

```
static class VoiceEffect
{
    SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    private volatile bool _isCurrentlySpeaking = false;

    /// <summary>Event handler. Fired when the SpeechSynthesizer object starts speaking asynchronously.</summary>
    private void StartedSpeaking(object sender, SpeakStartedEventArgs e)
    { _isCurrentlySpeaking = true; }
    /// <summary>Event handler. Fired when the SpeechSynthesizer object finishes speaking asynchronously.</summary>
    private void FinishedSpeaking(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    { _isCurrentlySpeaking = false; }

    private VoiceEffect _instance;
    /// <summary>Gets the singleton instance of the VoiceEffect class.</summary>
    /// <returns>A unique shared instance of the VoiceEffect class.</returns>
    public VoiceEffect GetInstance()
    {
        if(_instance == null)
        { _instance = new VoiceEffect(); }
        return _instance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor. Initializes the class assigning event handlers for the
    /// SpeechSynthesizer object.
    /// </summary>
    private VoiceEffect()
    {
        reader.SpeakStarted += new EventHandler<SpeakStartedEventArgs>(StartedSpeaking);
        reader.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(FinishedSpeaking);
    }

    /// <summary>Speaks stuff.</summary>
    /// <param name="str">The stuff to speak.</param>
    public void startSpeaking(string str)
    {
        reader.Rate = -2; // Voice  effects.
        reader.Volume = 100;

        // if the reader's currently speaking anything,
        // don't let any incoming prompts overlap
        while(_isCurrentlySpeaking)
        { continue; }

        reader.SpeakAsync(str);
    }

    /// <summary>Creates a new thread to speak stuff into.</summary>
    /// <param name="str">The stuff to read.</param>
    public void createVoiceThread(string str)
    {
        Thread voicethread = new Thread(() => startSpeaking(str)); // Lambda Process
        voicethread.IsBackground = true;
        voicethread.Start();
    }        
}
```

from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17153718/1137006

I call that by writing this in another class:

```
TextToSpeech.startSpeaking(text);
```

I want to know when that call is done and it has finished speaking.
Possibly as an event?
I can see the event inside the VoiceEffect class but I don't know how to get it to fire in the class that do the startSpeaking() call.
The reason I need to know is to change a WPF-control after something has been spoken.
Is that possible to add to this code?

---

**Edit: To clarify**

In my MainWindow class I can call multiple TextToSpeech from the file TextToSpeech.cs that has the VoiceEffect class and startSpeaking method.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextToSpeech.startSpeaking("Test1");
        TextToSpeech.startSpeaking("Test2");
        TextToSpeech.startSpeaking("Test3");
        TextToSpeech.startSpeaking("Test4");
    }
}
```

They will all wait for the one previous to be done before speaking and does also let the program continue forward during the time it's speaking.

I want to know if I can get an event or something when for example "Test2" has been spoken and then change a WPF-control in the MainWindow? For example hiding a Text label.

Comment: so this is a wpf app?

Comment: Yes, it is part of a WPF-app

Comment: You already have a SpeakCompleted event that you're already handling... What else do you need?

Comment: How do I get that event in another class that does the TextToSpeech.startSpeaking(text);? In my mainWindow class. I don't have an object to point to. The current method doesn't use a public one.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
       SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();

       reader.SpeakCompleted += Reader_SpeakCompleted;
  }

   void Reader_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e) {

   }
```

Comment: Nope. I need the event from the class I'm using. My class makes it possible to queue up multiple instances without locking the program from continuing forward.

Comment: Which class you are using?   VoiceEffect?

Comment: In my MainWindow class I just call TextToSpeech.startSpeaking(text); which calls that method in VoiceEffect. I never get a VoiceEffect object in MainWindow. That's the problem. I need it to retain the ability to queue up text but also to know when a specific text is done speaking.